# Деление на слоги. Для чего?

Tags: слоги

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, зачем нужно знать правила деления слов на слоги. Деление для переноса имеет прикладное значение, а на слоги? Вопрос возник из-за конфликта в школе. Я учила своих детей принципу восходящей звучности и исключениям с сонорными согласными, учитель в школе для упрощения понимания делит слово на слоги, как для переноса. Стоит ли настаивать на своем или смириться? Я не соглашусь со школой, если правильное деление на слоги: а) имеет прикладное значение (помощь в правописании, например) и б) такое задание есть в ЕГЭ и правила там по принципу восходящей звучности. Помогите разобраться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Деление на фонетические слова и слоги имеет прикладное значение только для транскрипции, для фонетического разбора. Собственно, Вы, вероятно, об этом и говорите. Учитель не имеет права ничего упрощать. От фонетики зависит орфоэпия - как ребёнок будет говорить. Для орфографии слоги не нужны, в ЕГЭ таких заданий нет, но если ему придётся учиться в вузе, где такие знания необходимы, он будет дезориентирован. Научите его правильно делить, а другие пусть делают, как хотят.

Правда, есть одно правило - "И-Ы после приставок на согласный": если разделить на слоги без-ин-те-рес-но, то ребёнок не поймёт, почему пишем БЕЗЫНТЕРЕСНО, а если правильно [бе-зын-ти(е)-ре-снъ], то всё понятно: как слышим, так и пишем. Так что есть прикладное значение.

А воевать с учителем - не воевать - Ваше дело.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила. Именно так я и сделала - мои делят правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Если подойти к вопросу философски, то очень даже необходимо, уметь делить слова на слоги. Читая слово по слогам, информация проникает в сознание - порциями. Как луч, отражается внутри ограненного алмаза, так и НОВАЯ информация - преломляется в сознании - учащегося. Импульсы между нейронами, под воздействием звукового колебания вызывают, поэтапное подключение всё новых и новых отделов, коры головного мозга.

Comment: Да, только нас учили делить: кош-ка, а по современным правилам - ко-шка. Или вы намекаете, что у нас (так как мы в детстве делили на слоги не так, как сейчас) не все отделы коры... подключились?